# Copy data in tables from one database server to another database server in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm really new to php and I need to create a script that will copy data from the table from one database server to another database server. But I don't know how to do that.
Also, I don't need to copy all the fields in that table there are some specific fields only that I want to copy.

For Example :

```
Database 1 server -  SampleTable 1 fields

id | control_number |   date    | received | finished |
2  |    222222      |   2019    |    2018  |   2019   |

Database 2 server - SampleTable 2 fields


id | control_number | received  | finished |
2  |    222222      |   2018    |    2019  |
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262876/how-to-copy-database-tables-and-each-record-from-one-database-server-to-another), but It didn't work for me.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: @AmanjotKaur check this. I've posted new question. It includes codes that I have tried.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622804/copying-data-from-two-different-database-server-using-pdo-php